# Total count across different columns in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

[image]

Please find the dataset above
I need to get the

```
1) RM count across the whole table and per column
2) GI count across whole table and per column
3) NA or blank across whole table and per column
```

I know how to get the count across columns
Need help with whole table

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can pivot your data, you can add count each column like so:

```
count(if [CL1] = 'RM' then 1 end) + count(if [CL2] = 'RM' then 1 end) + etc....
```

Repeat for GI.

For NA or blank, you can do something similar

```
count(if [CL1] = 'NA' OR ISNULL([CL1]) then 1 end) + count(if [CL2] = 'NA' OR ISNULL([CL1]) then 1 end) + etc....
```